# Label text not updating during file transfer ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having troubles trying to update a label during a fileupload file transfer. I essentially am trying to keep a running tab on the status of the file transfer. For whatever reason however I cannot get the label to update inside the function that I am initiating the background worker to do the file transfer. I can change the Label.Text before it enters the else statement before the file transfer (this is the part that states that there is a duplicate of a file in the desired directory).

I've been looking around for an answer for approximately two days and the conventional methods of putting the Label into an UpdatePanel and setting the UpdateMode="Conditional" and then manually calling UpdatePanel1.Update() did not work.

Other questions also addressed the problem of having errant javascript in the page and that is not the case in this situation. I do not have any javascript on this web page.

I have also tried setting the Label.Text through both a ui background worker and through a loop that ran in the SaveFile() method after the background worker for the fileupload was started. Neither worked.

Also of note I have noticed that the Label.Text contents will update when I assign it through any medium, but it does not refresh the UI on the client side until the file transfer completes, which renders the progress report in the label moot.

Here is the HTML snippet

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <!-- Here's all of the contents for the asp part of the page -->
        <br />
        <h1>Upload File</h1>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgr" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="UploadLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </p>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadFile" runat="server"/>
        <br />
        <!--  OnClick="BtnUpload_Click"  -->
        <asp:Button ID="BtnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload File" OnClick="BtnUpload_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="RebootLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnReboot" runat="server" Text="Reboot" OnClick="BtnReboot_Click" />

</form>
```

Here is the relevant .cs methods

```
protected void SaveFile(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    try
    {
        String savePath = Resources.Resource.INSTALLER_PATH + UploadFile.FileName;         //save path on the server
        //check to see if there are any duplicate file names in the destination
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(savePath))
        {
            //then the file already exists and we should notify the user
            //do not write anything to the directory if this occurs
            UploadLabel.Text = "A file with the desired name already exists in the destination directory, please choose another file";
        }
        else
        {
            //then it is safe to upload the file to the TOD
            /*UploadLabel.Text = "Uploading file...";
            BtnReboot.Enabled = false;
            System.Drawing.Color temp = BtnReboot.BackColor;
            BtnReboot.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            UploadFile.SaveAs(savePath);    //upload the file to the TOD
            BtnReboot.BackColor = temp;
            BtnReboot.Enabled = true;
            UploadLabel.Text = "Finished uploading file.";*/
            try
            {
                UploadLabel.Text = "Uploading file...";
                uploadingFileName = savePath;       //get the path that is being uploaded to
                uploadingFileSize = UploadFile.PostedFile.ContentLength;        //get the size in bytes to upload
                BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
                bgw.DoWork += Bgw_DoWork;
                bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
                //progress report ui worker
                BackgroundWorker uiWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
                uiWorker.DoWork += UiWorker_DoWork;
                uiWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
                bgw.Dispose();
                uiWorker.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                UploadLabel.Text = err.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Web.HttpException err)
    {
        UploadLabel.Text = "Exception: " + err.ToString();
    }
    catch (System.InvalidOperationException err)
    {
        UploadLabel.Text = "Exception: " + err.ToString();
    }
    catch (System.UriFormatException err)
    {
        UploadLabel.Text = "Exception: " + err.ToString();
    }
}

private void UiWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(uploadingFileSize != 0)
    {
        //redraw the label
        if (File.Exists(uploadingFileName))
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(uploadingFileName);
            long currentSize = fi.Length;
            UploadLabel.Text = "Progress: " + currentSize + " / " + uploadingFileSize;
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Bgw_DoWork
/// Asynchronous function that gets called for the background worker to start work
/// Is used for file uploading. Combined with the timer to give feedback on current upload progress
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void Bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    UploadLabel.Text = "Hello from the bgw";
    UploadFile.SaveAs(uploadingFileName);
    uploadingFileSize = 0;
    uploadingFileName = "";
    //BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    //worker.ReportProgress(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you want to do the both actions (Uploading file and updating the label) with the same request. Consider the fact that once you upload a file you're sending a stream of bytes to the server and you need to wait for the response and the response would be after file being completely uploaded. So what you need to do is triggering 2 ajax requests throw jquery( $.ajax() method) or XMLHttpRequest. Using update panels is not an option for what you're up to do.

Take a look into this to see how you can do it : http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: The problem with this is that you have to use some kind of PHP with ajax to upload the file to the server. I was using ASP.net because I could change the file size limitations on the upload. With PHP you cannot, which posed a problem. At least that's what I've been reading and have found out recently. I could be wrong.